# How can I print a batch of files with custom printer settings?

Tags: pdf, batch, printing

I have a collection of A3-size (tabloid size) PDF drawings which I would like to print as a batch.

[image]

The particular printer I am using doesn't automatically check the paper size of the document - it always defaults to A4 (letter) size paper unless told otherwise. I need to go into the printer settings and tell the printer to use A3 size paper.

[image]

A batch printing utility like [DarkStorm's Batch Print Handler](http://sourceforge.net/projects/darkstormsbph/) would be good for this. However this particular utility doesn't support changing the paper size settings or other printer settings.

How can I go about batch printing these PDFs with a particular paper size?

Answer (score 0):

[Commercial solution](http://www.printandshare.info), but if you set this to Automatic it takes the size of the document.
[image: Autopatic page size]

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer I support SumatraPDF which runs on Windows (or perhaps *may* work in Wine)

The Command Line Printing in recent Pre-Release was enhanced to cover many formats using "paperkind" which can be any Windows registered custom "Form" shapes such as half page left OR half page right etc. but here you would simply use "paper=A3".

There are limitations, such as it runs "Print As Image" only, which results in large spool files.

For PDF vector file outputs, NOTHING can equal Acrobat, but GhostScript is the best programmable solution.